# Low gpa for grad school in my case

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school

I am a college senior with 3.2 math gpa, who aspire to go to math grad school. I cannot stay in college any longer due to financial difficulties. My junior year I lost focus and got bunch of C's. Tried so hard my remaining two years and did well on analysis I/II, math stats, and complex, and some other applied math classes. But got C in abstract algebra I again (this time was really due to my father passing suddenly, I was quite depressed for months). My application right now is:

- gpa:3.2
- three summers of research one in physics, one in applied, one in pure math
- I got two good, one excellent LOR to expect
- still have chances to take GRE twice
- some teaching and tutoring experience for the math dept.

What are my chances of getting to good grad school? 
Or do I have to do Masters program and detour a bit? 
Should I even apply next fall?

Thank you for all insights.

Comment: Please don't mark duplicate. I deleted my previous posts due to it was placed in a wrong section. I want to get some prespective

Comment: We can't speculate regarding your specific chances of admission. See the [help/on-topic] on "Can I ask about my specific situation?" If you have a general question that isn't addressed by the marked duplicate, [edit] your question to remove the parts we can't answer and to highlight your general question.